# Type [SubscriptType] does not conform to protocol StringLiteralConvertible error

Tags: swift

Type `[SubscriptType]` does not conform to protocol `StringLiteralConvertible`

```
// JsonRequest.swift

class JsonRequest {
var title: String?
var postBody: String?
var coverImage: String?

init(json: NSDictionary){
    self.title = json["title"] as? String
    self.postBody = json["body"] as? String
    self.coverImage = json["img_url"] as? String
}
}

// ViewController.swift file

var posts = [JsonRequest]()

let feedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/json")
    // 2
    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: feedUrl!) {
        // 3
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var myJSON = JSON(jsonResult)
        let arrayLength = myJSON["dump"].array?.count

        if arrayLength != 0 {
            for postIndex in 0...arrayLength! - 1 {
                var postArray = myJSON["dump"][postIndex]["title"] as? [NSDictionary]
                for item in postArray {
                    posts.append(JsonRequest(json: item))
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to append from my JSON`["dump"][0, 1, 2]["title"]` to `postArray array`, save all this titles in the this array, but here is the this error. How can I fix it and save my titles in this Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cast `postArray` as `[NSDictionary]` because it is not `NSDictionary`.
But It is string and here is example code for you.

```
var posts = [String]()

    let feedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/en/feed")
    // 2
    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: feedUrl!) {
        // 3
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var myJSON = JSON(data:JSONData)
        let arrayLength = myJSON["dump"].array?.count

        if arrayLength != 0 {
            for postIndex in 0...arrayLength! - 1 {
                var post = myJSON["dump"][postIndex]["title"].stringValue
                posts.append(post)
                println(posts)
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Update your code this way:

**JsonRequest.swift**

```
class JsonRequest {
var title: String?
var postBody: String?
var coverImage: String?

init(json: JSON){
    self.title = json["title"].stringValue
    self.postBody = json["body"].stringValue
    self.coverImage = json["img_url"].stringValue
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
var posts = [JsonRequest]()

    let feedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/en/feed")
    // 2
    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: feedUrl!) {
        // 3
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var myJSON = JSON(data:JSONData)
        let arrayLength = myJSON["dump"].array?.count
        var dict = myJSON["dump"]

        if arrayLength != 0 {
            for postIndex in 0...arrayLength! - 1 {
                var tempDict = dict[postIndex]
                posts.append(JsonRequest(json: tempDict))
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: On the this line `posts.append(post)` it prints the next error: `'NSString' is not a subtype of 'JsonRequest'`

Comment: This is just an example where I take array of string but you can modify it as per your need.

Comment: I had added my `JsonRequest`  file too. May be it will help you